# Query about Convolutional Neural Network

Tags: python, mnist, conv-neural-network

If I train my CNN to identify MNIST handwritten digits using "images" (arrays) with black background (value 0):

[image]

Will it be able to identify digits in images with white background?

[image]

What about vice versa? If the answer is yes (background color doesn't matter) what would be the explanation? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No. It wouldn't work directly. If you think about the problem of classifying digits, what we want to do is take a coordinate point (of 28x28 numbers from 0-255), and map it to a digit 0-9. If we fit such a function that performs this task, you can't take the opposite point and expect it to work.

Imagine a simpler case where we have points in 2D (coordinates of 2 numbers), and fit a straight line through it. Now we transform the data by moving the points (the inverse for example), the line doesn't fit anymore, and neither does our model.

However, a CNN that trains and performs well on the first dataset in theory should be able to train and perform well on the second.